# Insert constant in php require statement

Tags: php

I would like to add a pass the values declared as a constant inside a require statement. However, i'm getting a warning message

> " Warning: require(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server
>   configuration by allow_url_include=0 in C:\wamp\www\project\test.php
>   on line 3"

```
   <?php define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/project/'); ?>


   <?php require(BASE_URL.'templates/menu.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Put your complete code here.

Comment: Don't use the HTTP protocol to include code. Think about it for a moment...

Comment: The error message say it all. You have `allow_url_include=0` in your `php.ini` which turns off the ability to include/require from a URL. Change `allow_url_include=1` in `php.ini` and it will work. _Error messsages are there to be read._

Comment: "whoch turns off the ability to include/require from a URL" for very good reasons

Comment: @PeeHaa You are probably right. But as we cannot be aware of the OP's reasons and requirements, I find it best to just provided a reason for the error and let the OP make the decisions. __They will ignore any warnings we may give that they dont want to see anyway__

Comment: I strongly disagree with that sentiment. Posts like that are one of the reasons there are so many vulnerable applications out there. People will stumble upon it and think "great! That solves my problem." And now *you* are responsible for even more vulnerable applications.